# how to check empty column in python

Tags: python, django, django-models

how can i check if i have an empty column in my queryset?

this is my code :

```
        mastercard_percent = ClientPaymentOption.objects.filter(name='MasterCard', client=client).values_list('itemcharged',flat=True)
        if mastercard_percent == [None]:
            print 'empty'
        print mastercard_percent
```

and i got only this:

```
[None]
```

i try also in my code to become:

```
            if mastercard_percent == [None]:
                print 'empty'
            print mastercard_percent
```

but it also print :

```
[None]
```

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check the values of the column

like `if not mastercard_percent[0]: print 'empty'`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the expression be like:

```
print 'empty' if mastercard_percent == []
print mastercard_percent
```

In case that you're looking for an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of `repr(mastercard_percent)` ? If its value truly is `[None]`, then a comparison with `[None]` should work:

```
>>> a = [None]
>>> a == [None]
True
```